# PromotedState of modern news pages is 0 after publishing - why?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

In one tenant we see modern news that were published but have their `PromotedState` flag still being set to 0. We expect it to be 2 since they are published news articles.

I verified the value being 0 by looking at the list item's field values. The `FirstPublishedDate` value is missing (or empty) as well for these news.

[image]

The wrong `PromotedState` prevents the news from appearing in several web parts that show published news.

What else apart from publishing a modern news page is necessary to get the `PromotedState` to 2?

Answer (score 0):

Narf. This was a human error.

- PromotedState=0 => this is a page
- PromotedState=1 => this is a news
  post, not published
- PromotedState=2 => this is a news post,
  published

The problem was that the "news" was no news. It was a page.